# How to pass variable to GET request after receiving it from POST request

Tags: javascript, backend

Can't figure out how to pass a variable to GET request after receiving it from the frontend.

```
 app.post('/subcategories', (req, res) => {
  //receive category id from front
   const category_id = req.body.category;
 })

 app.get('/subcategories', (req, res) => {
    // need to replace the 25 with the variable I recieved from the above POST request
    const category_id = 25;
    db.query('SELECT subcategory_name FROM subcategories WHERE category_id=(?)',
    [category_id],
    (err, result) =>{
      res.send({result})
    });
 })
```

Comment: So who is _making_ this GET request, after you processed the previous POST request?

Comment: how did you passed the request object into post method?? ` //receive category id from front` this should be send from front. 
in post request you send the request ton receiving it

Comment: What if person A sends a POST request with 23, person B sends a POST request with 21 and then person A sends a GET request? What's the expected result? If you expect `category_id` to be 23, you either need some kind of authentication or session.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the category_id to GET using query parameters.

Do something like :

```
/subcategories?category_id=25
```

catch it in the GET api using :

```
let category_id = req.query.category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `category_id` as a query when making a get request and grab the `category_id` in the `'/subcategories'` route using `req.query`.

make get requests like this.

```
/subcategories?categoryid=25
```

get it in a query object like this.

```
let categoryId = req.query.categoryid
```

Comment: Is there anything else I have to do? Right now req.query.category_id is returning 'undefined'

Comment: you must make a get request like this  `/subcategories?categoryid=25` in order to receive `categoryid` in query object